# Form Validation with Bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem with understanding the building validation forms. In bootstrap current documentation there is a piece of JS code (so called starter code):

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

and it works fine but what should I do if i want to implement password check, for example? If i inderstand it right Bootstrap has css classes :valid and :invalid which run when the field is empty. I want to fire them when some condition is the (ie password less than 8 symbols).

```
<form id="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword1" id="pass1" placeholder="password" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid password.
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the pattern attribute. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> **pattern** 
>   A regular expression that the control's value is checked
>   against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some
>   subset. Use the title attribute to describe the pattern to help the
>   user. This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is
>   text, search, tel, url, email, or password, otherwise it is ignored.
>   The regular expression language is the same as JavaScript RegExp
>   algorithm, with the 'u' parameter that makes it treat the pattern as a
>   sequence of unicode code points. The pattern is not surrounded by
>   forward slashes.

For example, the following will validate that the password is at least 8 characters with upper case, lower case and numbers:

```
<form id="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword1" id="pass1" placeholder="password" 
                   pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$"
                   required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Passwords should be a minimum of 8 characters and include at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one number.
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Pattern solves a specific problem but how to do it more generally? For example how do I make a validation for two fields (password and password confirmation match)? How to modify my JS code for that (assume that there is one more field - "password confirmation"?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. If you need to do something more complex than the built-in constraints allow, you can use custom javascript and set the validation state of the field using `input.setCustomValidity()`. MDN has good docs on HTML5 constraint validation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation